# How can I increase the size of icons and fonts in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, fonts

I use glasses and I need increase the size of icons and fonts in Kubuntu desktop, how can I do that?

Comment: It might be useful if you say which version of kubuntu you are using. 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System Settings** by clicking K button on the left bottom.

You will have a menu like this:

[image]

Go to **Application Appearance**  and then there go to **Icons** and **Advanced**. There you can change Icon size.

[Kde WIKI](https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-runtime/kcontrol/icons/index.html)

For changing fonts again from **System Settings Menu** go to **System Administration** and then **Font Management**

[image]

You can change fonts and their sizes there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start up Kubuntu. I'll use the latest stable version, which is Kubuntu 22.10 (as of me writing this)

[image: Original screenshot]

Let's open up Settings and change the scaling (from 100% to 150% - other values should work fine too, but that's what I tried it with).

[image]

Press Apply, then reboot. Once you've rebooted, the new scaling should be applied.

[image]